# Is there a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ that admits a non-Archimedean order?

Tags: field-theory, ordered-fields

We know any Archimedean ordered field can be embedded as a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, but is there a subfield, on which there is another order instead of the one imposed by $\mathbb{R}$, such that it’s not Archimedean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  For instance, if $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is any transcendental number, then you can order the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha$ is infinitely large.  Explicitly, you can say a rational function in $\alpha$ is positive iff the leading coefficients of its numerator and denominator have the same sign.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So it means it’s much harder to determine the number of different orders of a subfield of \mathbb{R} especially when it’s a transcendental extension of \mathbb{Q}.